# read JSON value in ASP.NET Core web api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

What is the best approach to get value from:

```
{"profileObj":{"Name":"xxx","FirstName":"xxx","FastName":"xxx","Email":"xxx"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using System.Text.Json

```
//your json

var json= "{\"profileObj\":{\"Name\":\"xxx\",\"FirstName\":\"xxx\",\"FastName\":\"xxx\",\"Email\":\"xxx\"}}";

using System.Text.Json;
.....

var jD= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);

var value =jD.profileObj;

var name= value.Name;
```

or you can install Newtonsoft.Json nuget package and use this code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
.....
var jD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
......
```

classes

```
public class ProfileObj
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string FastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public ProfileObj profileObj { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @FarhadZamani Thank you. I updated my answer.  Net text.json should be enough. It is a very simple object.

Comment: Yes, that's enough. However, adding namespace can help the user more